# Не срабатывает Timer (ActionListener)

Tags: java, таймер, action

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему каждый 3 секунды не выводится сообщение "Hello"?

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

    public class Program{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            try{
                Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        System.out.println("Hello");
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Никаких ошибок не выводится. Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не успевает выполниться код в `ActionListener`-е, потому что завершается главный поток. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
try{
   Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
   });
   timer.setRepeats(true);
   timer.start();
   Thread.sleep(6000);   // главный поток засыпает на 6 секунд
} catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Благодаря `Thread.sleep(6000);` тут главный поток засыпает на 6 секунд, поэтому ваш код в `ActionListener`-е успевает выполниться 2 раза.

Comment: Благодарю! Но а как же мне быть? Я пишу программу, которая будет обрабатывать большое количество файлов, и периодичность обработки должна быть несколько минут.

Comment: Т.е. пока другой фоновый поток не закончит работу, главный не завершится, я правильно понял?

Comment: Нет не правильно, фоновый имеет другой стек